# Is this study plan sufficiently general, or overly specialized?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, analysis, self-learning, learning

My current study plan is in order below. I will be completing these textbooks in this order one at a time.

I have been told that I don't have textbooks in my plan that approach topology in a general matter, but instead my focus is very narrow, meaning I may miss many important ideas.

> **Question:** Is this a valid concern? Is the same true for either Algebra, or Analysis?

---

- Cohn - Classic Algebra
- Rudin - Principles of Mathematical Analysis
- Lee - Topological Manifolds
- Cohn - Basic Algebra
- Rudin - Complex Analysis
- Lee - Smooth Manifolds
- Cohn - Further Algebra
- Rudin - Functional Analysis
- Lee - Riemannian Manifolds

---

Note: My calculus is sufficiently built. For meta discussion on the **close votes, please go** [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17346/learning-tag-opinion-based)

---

List constructed with advice from comments and the one answer(added are bold). It seems to be potentially excessively long(added bold):

- Cohn – Classic Algebra
- **Axler – Linear Algebra Done Right**
- **Zorich – Mathematical Analysis I**
- Rudin – Principles of Mathematical analysis
- **Dugundji - Topology**
- Lee – Topological Manifolds
- **Zorich – Mathematical Analysis II**
- Rudin – Real & Complex Analysis
- Cohn – Basic Algebra
- **J.P May – A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology**
- **Ddo Carmo - Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces**
- Lee – Smooth Manifolds
- Cohn – Further Algebra
- Rudin – Functional Analysis
- Lee – Riemannian Manifolds

Comment: Firstly, it is very *clear* what I am asking. I even put it in a `>` box beside '**Question:**'.

Secondly, how could a self-learning, and learning tagged question **not** be opinion based?

Comment: First in the related section 'How to effectively study math?' - 42 Up-votes. That certainly doesn't sound opinion based ;).

Comment: For one, what *is* the question? Is the question whether you include enough topology/algebra/analysis in your study plan?

Comment: @FredrikMeyer Is  Topological Manifolds -> Smooth Manifolds -> Riemannian manifolds a specialized exposure to topology and its extensions?

Is the same true for my Cohn and Rudin study plan?

Comment: @Clarinetist No, it is to open my exposure to the different fields so I have more ideas on what I want to do for graduate studies in 2017/2018 (after getting some experience(read: money) as a working mathematician)

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge
Lee's books would be more accurately described as Differential Geometry texts.

For Topology, I recommend Dugundji - Topology (after Baby Rudin [princ. math analysis] and before Lee-Top. Mani.) and J.P. May - A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology (somewhere between Dugundji and Big Rudin [real&complex analysis]).

For Algebra, I recommend Axler - Linear Algebra Done Right somewhere in there (maybe before Baby Rudin) and Jacobson's Basic Algebra I & II (see tables of contents for each to see where they'd fit with Cohn's texts).

Comment: @BrianScholl Thank you for these recommendations, I will check them out at the library and consider them

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge Could you maybe send me your e-mail or something? I think your challenge idea is very good and maybe we could colaborate or something, I would be very interested in following your program. I couldn't find your e-mail in your profile, so.

Comment: Regarding general topology, it looks to me as if the first four chapters of Lee's book should be sufficient, if you only need the amount of general topology most people learn. I assume you'll be reading the "Real Analysis" part of Rudin's book as well, as that's important. I would make the fifth book (Rudin) a higher priority than the fourth (Cohn). Also, you say you have calculus covered, but few people in North America learn rigorous calculus to the right level, and Rudin only makes up for this partly. I recommend you have a glance at the table of contents o both volumes of Zorich's book...

Comment: ... after reading Rudin's to check if there are any important topics you're missing. Some of these will be covered by Lee's *Smooth Manifolds* anyway, so look for other things.

Comment: Let me add, after seeing your profile, that very few people would be able to learn all of this in one year.

Comment: @Mike Thank you for your suggestions, I will definitely take a look at Zorich's books, perhaps my calculus isn't fully built. I suspect I won't be able to complete my list in one year and knowing that I won't  be rushing any of the reading if I don't understand it. When I fail, I will still endure to finish the list as soon as possible.

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli I will add an email to the account soon. Thank you for your interest, the user 'Jasper Loy' created the list, including the three Marsden&Weinstein Calculus books at the start, but he hasn't yet started the task and will be starting from the calculus books that I have skipped on the first of January 2015. Five other people have said that they will be undertaking the challenge since I have started which is interesting.

Comment: @Mike Hey. Thank you again for your comments. Where would you recommend putting the Zorich books into the list? I do want to add them, and I think maybe the first volume will go third(after the potentially added in Axler - Linear algebra, with Cohn still first)

Comment: I don't know. I don't think you'll be gaining much by reading Axler's book in addition to Cohn's. I believe if you understand what's in Cohn, you won't need it, as Cohn appears to cover the same material at a higher level. I'm not sure what your goals are, but for most people it would make sense to focus on one analysis book and one algebra book first, and then re-evaluate what you want to do afterwards. Cohn is fine for algebra and either Zorich I and II, or Rudin, or Apostol's book (or another) would be fine for analysis. Really taking the time to absorb this basic analysis and algebra...

Comment: ...is the most important thing to do, because although there is more material later on, those two subjects are where you're really introduced to the main ways of thinking in mathematics. Personally, I wouldn't want to feel as if I had to rush through this material to keep to a schedule. I'd rather take the time to enjoy it.

Comment: @Mike Are you the same Mike? I am not sure if I have tagged you correctly. Yes that is a valid point(not rushing through it), I am taking it as fast as I can while fully understanding it, and so far I am finding Cohn's Classic Algebra brutually painful to work through, whereas Axler seems very friendly. I will work through both, since the topics that are the same I can work through both of them. Same holds for the Analysis in my opinion. Once I work through it in one, working through the others is time inexpensive.

Comment: Yes, I'm the same Mike. What is your background in terms of mathematics with proofs?

Comment: @Mike I have done Discrete Math I&II, Analysis I,CalculusI&II&III, Abstract algebra I, Real analysis, Statistics I&II,Linear algebra I, Optimisation theory. So I have had exposure to proofs in most of those, but I didn't really study very hard on anything beyond being able to answer questions for Algebra, Calculus and Analysis, so only Optimsation theory and Discrete math were learnt properly

Comment: Which is why I am needing to work on these subjects before I go into third year, else I am going to have a heap of trouble. That and I need to overload on courses, since I really want to do some that won't come back for awhile, as well as taking the required courses

Comment: What was your experience like in abstract algebra? Sorry, the third year of what?

Comment: @Mike I did badly in abstract Algebra, which was a year ago now. We covered Rings, Fields, Isomorphisms, subgroups. That course was combined with number theory(which I did well in), so we probably didn't cover too much. Third year of a pure math major

Comment: So you're doing a math degree at the moment, and you'd like to learn material from courses you didn't study properly the first time. Is that right?

Comment: @Mike Yes, I suppose so, but also content from courses I am going to do in the next year(Complex analysis, Functional analysis, Abstract algebra II, Topology, Differential geometry)

Comment: I think you have the most to gain by finding an algebra text that you're comfortable with and that covers what you were supposed to know from the first course relatively directly. Same goes for analysis. What are you not enjoying about Cohn's book?

Comment: @Mike The wall of text feels so dense with information, it takes me over an hour per page, especially if there are any exercises. The exercises feel very difficult, as if the content above them is insufficient to solve them without very significant playing around. Maybe I just described a good textbook for all I know, maybe this is where the true learning comes from.

Comment: An hour a page is okay for learning math, as long as you're understanding it as you read it. What proportion of the exercises are you able to solve?

Comment: @Mike I don't move on until I finish them all, but truthfully I find myself greatly demotivated with some of them I can't solve without asking for help(E.g. About 7 you can see in my questions page)

Comment: Would you like it better if you had solutions?

Comment: @Mike I have every second solution in the back, but what I think would make it a better book, would be more exercises of varying difficulty, or maybe better layout of what is important in the chapter.

Comment: I think what you're experiencing is normal. As long as you can follow the proofs and the solutions of the exercises when they're shown to you, it means that you're learning things. It may feel a bit different to you because you feel as though you're "supposed to" know this. But if you're able to take some of that pressure off yourself, you may be able to go back to enjoying learning things, even though you find them difficult. In your circumstances, I think you might be better off with Apostol's book than either Rudin's or Zorich's. It's probably a bit easier than both of them, certainly ...

Comment: ...shorter than Zorich's. Have a look at this bibliography ( https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm ) for some alternatives in algebra if you really don't like Cohn's book.

Comment: @Mike Thank you for your comments and advice, I will have a look and see what I can do. I'll try sticking through with Cohn for a bit longer to make sure it isn't just a rough start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're pretty well starting from scratch (that is, after taking standard first and second year courses in discrete mathematics, calculus, and linear algebra), to get a well rounded foundation in **undergraduate** mathematics you might consider:

- Set Theory: Halmos *Naive Set Theory*.
- Topology: Munkres *Topology*.
- Algebra: Herstein *Topics in Algebra*.
- Analysis: Rudin *Principles*.
- Geometry: do Carmo *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*.
- Number Theory:  Burton *Elementary Number Theory*.

The list for **1st-year graduate level** maths would be different.  For this case I have written a comment below, but also consider the following links:

- http://www.math.harvard.edu/quals/index.html
- http://math.berkeley.edu/programs/graduate/prelim-exams
- http://www.math.cornell.edu/m/Graduate/prog_content.html
- http://www.math.columbia.edu/programs-math/graduate-program/what-graduate-students-are-assumed-to-know/

Comment: Very nice list, I will have a look at these books over the next few days. Thank you! Also, do you already have a constructed list for first year graduate?

Comment: For 1st-yr graduate I would recommend: Algebraic topology: Hatcher/Lee/Massey. Real analysis: Folland/Royden/Rudin. Complex analysis: Rudin/Ahlfors/Conway. Functional analysis: Rudin/Conway/Yosida. Algebra: Dummit&Foote/Artin/Lang. Differential geometry: Lee/Spivak/do Carmo. Number theory: Serre/Hardy&Wright/Ireland&Rosen. Algebraic geometry: Dummit&Foote/Hartshorne/Harris.  Which individual book(s) you choose in each area depends on one's tastes and which book one 'takes to'.

Comment: Thank you G.S. this is very helpful!